# Custom UINavigationBar with LargeTitles not working in IB

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

So I created MyViewController class with .xib file. 
I drag an dropped a NavBar and placed it within the limits of the Safe Area.

MyViewController is instanaciated somewhere else and put inside a UINavigationController.

```
let myVC = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myVC)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

inside MyViewController I set

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

So the default navbar of the UINavigationController is not shown and I see only my custom navbar and I can program his behaviour manually and stuff.

Now.. in the IB I tick the **Prefers Large Titles** box but nothing seems to change anywhere. Any ideas ?

No I dont want to put my VC xib into a UINavigationController, I want to keep it a UIViewController so programatically I can use it in other places as I please and have my own UINavigationBar separately.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles

Comment: @ElTomato yeah, thats what I do by checking the Box in the IB